# Emf induced by a circular region of magnetic field on a variety of shapes

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

From Faraday's Law

$\epsilon$=-$\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ where $\phi$  is the flux

Now this, does this induced emf only act circular,(i.e the current is flowing in a circular path.) Can it also be coerced to flow any path we choose(like place a hexagonal(closed) shaped wire in a region of magnetic field which is changing at the rate of $\frac{dB}{dT}$ and make the rest of the surface extremely resistive)  and does the emf change or remain the same.

To be explicit, consider this example[image]

Now say I consider three cases when no rectangular lop is present, when one loop(inside) is present and when only outerloop is present.

Let current in the cases respectively be $I'$ $I''$ $I'''$

Is the emf same in all the cases?

Note magnetic field is present in only circular region.

Answer (score 0):

The emf induced in a closed loop depends on the rate of change of magnetic flux linked with that loop.

[image]

In the diagram above, the emf induced in the circle alone, the square alone and the loop coloured red is the same and greater than the emf induced in the rectangle.
The induced emf is related to the loop and does not reside in any specific parts of the loop.

Induced currents are a consequence of there being an emf induced and do not influence the magnitude of the emf induced in a loop.
Where currents flow and their magnitude and direction depend on the induced emf and the resistance of the various parts of the loop and the configuration of the loop(s).
Thus, to answer your question about the actual currents in the loops requires more information from you as to the resistance of various parts of the loops and where the loops are connected with a conducting path.

[image]

Total flux linked with square $= BA + 0 = BA$ and this is the flux that is changing.

Comment: could you provide some clarity as to how the circular loop and the square(red loop) have same emf?

Comment: The induced electric field. $\vec{E}$ $\propto$ $r$ where $r$ is distance from the centre. So I fail to understand how the field acts on the corners of the square(red loop) as there is no field acting there?

Comment: You state *Note magnetic field is present in only circular region.*  This fixes the rate of change of flux in the circular loop and any loop outside the circular loop. $\vec E \propto r$ is valid within the circular loop provided the change in magnetic field is uniform over the enclosed area. Once outside the circular loop the rate of change of flux within any loop is the same as that within the circular loop.

Comment: I have added an extra diagram to my answer which might help you understand what is going on.

Comment: thank you but one more thing. So if we consider any loop which enclosed the circlular magnetic field, however big the loop may be, will there be emf induced on the boundaries?

Comment: is it also possible to predict magnitude of electric field acting for example in the corners of the square loop.

Comment: Also why can't Lorentz force be used here? Isn,t farday's law from lorentz force eqn.

Comment: The emf will be induced in the big loop, to predict the electric field at the corners is not possible without further information and Faraday's law is independent of the Lorentz force. If you have further questions start a new post.

Comment: Sorry but how do we determine the fields? at the corners